# Angular UI router only loading ui-view content on manual URL update

Tags: express, angular-ui-router

I have started a MEAN application in which I am trying to implement angular-ui-router (for the first time).
Initially loading the content from the base url (localhost:3000) works as expected, and internally navigating via links using ui-sref also works correctly.  The url is updated and the page's content is correct.
However, what I have is a very small layout page with 2 named views, and when I try to manually navigate to a route, what I get is *only* the content for one of the named views.

Here is my express server file:

```
//includes
var express             = require('express');
var logger              = require('morgan');
var bodyParser          = require('body-parser');
var expressSession      = require('express-session');
var cookieParser        = require('cookie-parser');
var passport            = require('passport');
var mailer              = require('express-mailer');
var fs                  = require('fs');
var extend              = require('util')._extend;
var ensureLoggedIn      = require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn;
var views               = __dirname + '/public';

//determine environment
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

//init express app
var app = express();
app.set('views', views);

//general middleware
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
});
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: { secure: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development' ? 'auto' : true }
}));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development')
{
  app.locals.pretty = true;
}
app.use(express.static(views));

//start server
var args = process.argv.slice(2);
var port = args[0] || 3000;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('express server running on port: ' + port);
});
module.exports = app;
```

Here is my angular app file:

```
module angularApp {
  'use strict';

  var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp', [
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.router'
  ]);

  angular.module('angularApp')

  .config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
          "headerView": { templateUrl: 'includes/_header.html' },
          "contentView": { templateUrl: 'home.html' }
        }
      })
      .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        views: {
          "headerView": { templateUrl: 'includes/_header.html' },
          "contentView": { templateUrl: 'login/index.html' }
        }
      })
      .state('users', {
        url: '/user',
        views: {
          "headerView": { templateUrl: "includes/_header.html" },
          "contentView": { templateUrl: "user/index.html" }
        },
        data: {
          activeArea: 'Users'
        }
      })
      .state('scheduling', {
        url: '/scheduling',
        views: {
          "headerView": { templateUrl: "includes/_header.html" },
          "contentView": { templateUrl: "scheduling/index.html" }
        }
      })
      .state('checkin', {
        url: '/checkin',
        views: {
          "headerView": { templateUrl: "includes/_header.html" },
          "contentView": { templateUrl: "checkin/index.html" }
        }
      })
      .state('admin', {
        url: '/admin',
        views: {
          "headerView": { templateUrl: "includes/_header.html" },
          "contentView": { templateUrl: "admin/index.html" }
        }
      })
      .state('error', {
        url: '/error',
        views: {
          "headerView": {templateUrl: 'includes/_header.html' },
          "contentView": { templateUrl: 'error.html' }
        }
      })
      ;
  }])
  ;
}
```

Here is my index.jade

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  include includes/_head.jade
  body(ng-app="angularApp").black
    div(ui-view="headerView")
    .content.row-fluid
      div(ui-view="contentView")
```

Here is includes/_header.jade

```
.header(ng-controller="HeaderController as header")
  nav.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top(role="navigation")
    div.container
      div.navbar-header
        button.navbar-toggle(type="button", data-toggle="collapse", data-target=".navbar-collapse")
          span.sr-only | Toggle navigation
          span.icon-bar
          span.icon-bar
          span.icon-bar
        a(ui-sref="home").navbar-brand Academy Manager
      div.navbar-collapse.collapse
        ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right(ng-if="header.NavigationItems.length > 0")
          li(ng-repeat="item in header.NavigationItems track by $index")
            a(ui-sref="{{item.name}}", ui-sref-active="active") {{item.label}}
```

Here is (as an example) scheduling/index.jade

```
  .content-view-area.container
    h1 Scheduling Area
```

I'm using gulp to compile the jade files into html.  The html files live in the 'public' folder with the following structure:

```
public
  index.html
  includes
    _header.html
  scheduling
    index.html
```

If I go to the application's base URL (localhost:3000), everything works fine, and I get the full contents of the home page.  If I click on the 'Scheduling' nav item, again, everything is fine, and I get the full contents of the scheduling page, but if I do a refresh while at localhost:3000/scheduling then all I get is the following (from page source):

```
<div class="content-view-area container">
  <h1>Scheduling Area</h1>
</div>
```

I can see that neither my header with all my scripts and styles is there, nor is the index.html content.  All that is there is what should be getting loaded into my 'contentView' named view.
Can anyone please clue me in on what's going on?